# Use the Stokes' Theorem to find the work of the vector field $ \overrightarrow{F}$

Tags: vector-analysis

I have the following exercise:
"Use the Stokes' Theorem to find the work of the vector field $ \overrightarrow{F}=x^2 \hat{i}+2x \hat{j}+z^2\hat{k}$ along the anti-counterclockwise oriented area of the ellipse $ 4x^2+y^2=4$."
$$$$
I have done the following:
Since the  Ellipse is on the $ xy $ plane,  $ \hat{n}=\hat{k}$.

$ \nabla \times \overrightarrow{F}=2 \hat{k}$

$d \sigma= dxdy $

$\oint_C{\overrightarrow{F}}dR=\iint_S{\nabla \times \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n} }d \sigma=\iint_S{2\hat{k} \cdot \hat{k}}dxdy=\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-2 \sqrt{1-x^2}}^{2 \sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}dydx=\int_{-1}^1{8 \sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=4 \pi $.

Is my idea correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is right. Also, you don't need to do the integral explicitly, because from $\displaystyle \int_S{2\hat{k} \cdot \hat{k}}\,dx\,dy = 2\int_S\,d\sigma$ you can conclude that the result you are looking for is twice the area of the ellipse.

Comment: Isn't the formula of the area of the ellipse $\pi \cdot r_1 \cdot r_2$? In this case which is $r_1$ and which is $r_2$?

Comment: If you express the ellipse as $\displaystyle \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2 = 1$, then the area is $\pi\,a\,b$. In this case, $a=1$ and $b=2$.

Comment: A ok!! I understand!! Thanks a lot!!